# JQuery mobile transition at load page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, transition

I cannot figure out why my jquery mobile code does not work when reloading a page via a jquery mobile link/button.

Example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

  <div id="mydiv">wtf</div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <a href='page.html?reload=1' data-role="button" data-theme="a">Again</a>

</div><!-- /page -->


<script type="text/javascript">

function setmydiv()
{
   console.log('start');
   $("#mydiv").html('init');
}

$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
   console.log('init');
   setmydiv();

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The page load (first time) and displays "init" in the mydiv area.
When I press "Again" the mydiv text is still "wtf" (not replaced with "init")

Console log:

```
[00:49:16,081] GET http://www.vetgirig.nu/page.html [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 52ms]
[00:49:16,686] "init"
[00:49:16,686] "start"
--
[00:49:34,498] GET http://www.vetgirig.nu/page.html?reload=1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 46ms]
[00:49:34,387] "init"
[00:49:34,388] "start"
```

I have tried to use other events than pageinit but with no success...

If I replace:

```
<a href='page.html?reload=1' data-role="button" data-theme="a">Again</a>
```

with:

```
<input type='submit' data-role="button" value='Again' onClick="location.href = 'page.html?reload=1'"/>
```

Then everything works fine (but the transition - press button animation - is lost).
What am I missing...?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery mobile uses Ajax to load pages by default. You've got `pageinit` there instead of `document.ready` which is correct, but you could try:

- pagechange: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagechange/
- disabling the Ajax load on your link by adding `data-ajax="false"`

The reason your submit button is doing what you expect is that the javascript is literally reloading the page and refreshing the DOM, which the Ajax page loads don't do.

Comment: Just a thought: What I really would like is to be able to manipulate the DOM after ajax completes. Is that really not possible, sounds like a basic thing to me?!